# How to get current page context in CRM using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have to pass data to lookup field in CRM.

There is section with the buttons i made on account card. I also made some lookup fields on the account card. On click i have to pass some data to lookup field.

Here is the code i use to pass the data to lookup field, but i don't know how to get info about current page context. Is there any function doing that?

```
    var lookup = new Array();
    lookup[0] = new Object();
    lookup[0].id = recorid;
    lookup[0].name = recordname;
    lookup[0].entityType = entityname;
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("attributename").setValue(lookup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Xrm.Page.context.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/gg334511.aspx)